# Can IntelliJ 14 be used to work with IBM JDK 1.7?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ibm-jdk

We have a customer who uses the IBM JDK and so I would like to have that as an option to use within IntelliJ (normally, I only recent Oracle releases).  How can I install and setup IBM JDK 7 for use in IntelliJ such that I can switch between the two as required?  Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How can I install and setup IBM JDK 7 for use in IntelliJ Blockquote

1. Download and install the IBM JDK on your system
2. Open *File > Project Structure > [Platform Settings] > SDKs*
3. Click the Add Icon [image], select JDK, and add the IBM JDK by selecting the appropriate paths

> ...that I can switch between the two as required?

1. Open *File > Project Structure > [Project Settings] > Project*
2. Change the "Project SDK" setting.

You can also set on a module level by:

1. Open *File > Project Structure > [Project Settings] > Modules*
2. Select a module
3. Select the "Dependencies" tab
4. Change the Module SDK from "Project SDK" to the desired SDK definition

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't make this to work until I followed the steps here on this blog:

http://jaykhimani.blogspot.com/2015/02/making-intellij-idea-work-with-ibm-jdk-7.html

Basically I needed to add some obscure vm.jar